# Getting accurate total line count of a git repository for every commit

Tags: git

I am trying to create a script that collects the total line count of a git repository for every commit.

You can run

```
git ls-files | xargs wc -l
```

in a git repository which returns the total line count. In my case it returns following summaries for the first three commits:

```
0 total
8356 total
170931 total
```

However, it would be too slow to checkout and run this command for every commit so I decided to use

```
git log --shortstat --reverse --pretty=oneline
```

which returns the `insertions` and `deletions` done in every commit. The problem is that the numbers do not match with the previous command. Instead I get the following differences (everything after `=>` are my calculations, also "`x files changed`" prefix is not included):

```
[Nothing as this is the first commit] => 0 total
8357 insertions(+)                    => 8357 total
142972 insertions(+)                  => 151329 total
```

So, what I would like to know is that can I get accurate line count fast without the first command. The repository in question is almost 10 years old so I am not sure if that has anything to do with the difference.

**Update:** Git disregards empty lines added to the end of files but it alone does not explain this as the difference is far greater than the file count.

Comment: Maybe you could check with a simpler repository what causes `wc` to count the lines differently. Once you know what causes it, you could probably account for it and calculate the correct numbers. That being said, what is the purpose of having these numbers so accurately?

Comment: I just want to get accurate statistics. For the latest commit the difference is about 20% which is quite a lot in my opinion.

Comment: `git log --shortstat --reverse --pretty=oneline` does not show `0 total (there are no changes) ...` as you said. Are you sure this is the command you run?

Comment: I updated the question to be more clear. The 'total' is just my calculation about what the total line count should be if the differences are added together. The count of files changed is also not included above.

Comment: Also tested this with a newer repository and the results vary as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The discrepancy may also be explained by binary files. The diffstat does not count "lines" in binary files whereas `wc -l` will. The results of what `wc -l` outputs for these binary files is probably not very accurate.

Then care must be taken with the `xargs wc -l` invocation as it will not properly account for special chars in the printed file names (spaces for example). To avoid that problem use the `-z` flag for `git ls-files` which will cause the file names to be separated by a 0 byte instead of a newline and then use the `-0` argument to `xargs` so that it expects the file names as 0 byte delimited:

```
$ git ls-files -z | xargs -0 wc -l
```

Then there's no guarantee that `xargs` can fit all of the file names onto one invocation of `wc`, which means that it may have to call `wc -l` multiple times. This will result in multiple summaries that might easily be missed when intermixed with other output. Grepping for the "total" lines should make this more obvious:

```
$ git ls-files -z | xargs -0 wc -l | grep total
```

If I understand correctly that you always want the total count of lines for the whole repository at each commit, not just the count of changed lines in each respective commit, there's a simpler way to get that stat out of git:

```
$ git diff-tree --shortstat 4b825dc642cb6eb9a060e54bf8d69288fbee4904..
```

This uses `diff-tree` to compare the semi-magic "empty tree" (i.e. the state just before the first commit) with the current head. It therefore summarizes all the stats for all commits and removes the need for manually summing the numbers up.

For reference, the "empty tree" hash is what you get when hashing an empty string as a tree object with git:

```
$ echo -n | git hash-object -t tree --stdin
4b825dc642cb6eb9a060e54bf8d69288fbee4904
```